# Change first day of week centos server

Tags: linux, centos, locale, timezone

I have a CentOS 6.8 server. I need to change the first day of the week, to Monday.

I updated to: `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US`

```
week    7;19971130;7
    first_weekday   2
    first_workday   2
```

but I need to update without restarting,

important, I need to update for all users.

other data:

```
# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=


# locale day
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Sunday;Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday;Thursday;Friday;Saturday
```

Answer (score 1):

After editing the file you need to "compile" it into the binary archive actually used by programs.  I'm not sure of the exact command but according to the `localedef` command examples it should be something like

```
localedef -f UTF-8 -i us_US us_US.UTF-8
```